# Pass Laravel variable to Jquery function

Tags: jquery, laravel, function

Trying to pass Laravel variable from controller e.g. campaigns to another file of jquery function for ajax call. Normally in php we able to show the data using campaigns->id. I wanted to pass to the function and ajax call to show on the chart.

**index.php**

```
<div id="colouredBarsChart" class="ct-chart"></div>
<canvas id="myAreaChart" height="60"></canvas>

<script src="{{ asset('js/create-charts.js') }}"></script>
```

**create-charts.js**

```
( function ( $ ) {

var charts = {
    init: function () {
        // -- Set new default font family and font color to mimic Bootstrap's default styling
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#292b2c';

        this.ajaxGetCampaignReportData();

    },

    ajaxGetCampaignReportData: function () {
        // var urlPath =  'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/get-campaigns-chart-data';
        var urlPath =  '/engagements/{{campaign->id}}/get-campaigns-report-chart-data'; <------ ***Here***
        var request = $.ajax( {
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlPath,
            data: reference: campaign->score, <------------ ***Here***
            dataType:"json",
    } );

        request.done( function ( response ) {
            // console.log( response );
            charts.createCompletedJobsChart( response );
        });
    },

    /**
     * Created the Completed Jobs Chart
     */
    createCompletedJobsChart: function ( response ) {
    }
};
charts.init();
```

} )( jQuery );

Comment: Try this: `reference: '{{campaign->score}}'`

Comment: @MayankPandeyz No, that won't work. It's a `.js` file; you can't use `.blade` syntax (`{{ }}`) in a `.js` file.

Comment: @TimLewis sorry I missed it ( it is in js file ). Thanks for correcting me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In index.php render content into js-variable-definition:

```
<div id="colouredBarsChart" class="ct-chart"></div>
<canvas id="myAreaChart" height="60"></canvas>
<script>
var my_backend_var = "{{ $campaign->score }}";
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/create-charts.js') }}"></script>
```

and in your create-charts.js file you will have access to the js var then:

```
data: {reference:my_backend_var}
```

I added the brackets because you want to add a js-object to data property ;)

Comment: I feel like there's a `$` missing from the PHP variable, i.e.: `{{ $campaign->score }}`, might be a syntax/uninitialized constant error otherwise.

Comment: yes this might be :) I never used laravel so but I can imagine that its templating engine is also twig? I dont know, but if its like twig you wouldn´t need $

Comment: Laravel uses `.blade.php` syntax, which does require `$`. `{{ }}` is shorthand for `<?php e($variable) ?>`, and PHP will throw an error if you omit the `$`, as `campaign` is not a variable, but `$campaign` is. Again, this is just a guess; the original PHP variable was never mentioned, but I suspect that is the case. Leave for now, but if you get a comment that this doesn't work, suggest that change :)